# Used karate.fork to executes an OS command (SSH/SCP) but sysOut is not capturing output values

Tags: ssh, command, karate, scp

I have tried Karate framework feature karate.fork to execute SSH/SCP commands but sysOut is not capturing output values to validate. It returns only exitCode (0: represent script executed successfully, non-zero : represents the script error code).

I am facing 2 issues right now. It would be great if you guide me for below listed issues:-

Operating System : Windows 10

Code snippet - **ISSUE-1**

```
* def command =
            """
                function(line) {
                var proc = karate.fork({redirectErrorStream: false, useShell: true, line: line });
                proc.waitSync();
                karate.set('sysOut', proc.sysOut);
                karate.set('sysErr', proc.sysErr);
                karate.set('exitCode', proc.exitCode);
              }
            """
       * command('ssh user@<remote-server> "cd /data && ls"')
       * match sysOut contains 'volume1'
       * assert exitCode == 0
```

**Karate Debug Logs shows**

```
22:17:29.915 [1606236446563] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - inputrun1
22:17:29.916 [1606236446563] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - outputrun1
22:17:29.924 [1606236446563] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - volume1
22:17:29.954 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - **sysOut undefined**
```

Also, facing another **issue - ISSUE-2**

```
  * command('scp -r -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@<remote-server>:/data/volume1/ D:/karatetest/test/features/api/output')


20:07:59.947 [1606574279820-err]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate - 'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
20:07:59.947 [1606574279820-err]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate - operable program or batch file.
```

The above SCP command is working fine in command prompt and in powershell window separately. But it throws 'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command when I execute the same command in karate project inside VS code and when I ran karate command in VS code command prompt using java `-Dkarate.config.dir`=test/resources/ -cp test/karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main test/features/api/test_bash_script.feature. I have verified the environment variables path and physical path has scp application (C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH). Earlier this was working for me and suddenly it throws this exception. I am not sure this issue appearing because of I have uninstalled application and installed new app eclipse for java.

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, my guess is your new Eclipse does not get the `PATH` correctly. Yes, this is tricky to troubleshoot and I don't have any other tips other than trying various combinations and using absolute paths if needed.

I don't understand the first question. It all works for me, e.g: [`fork.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/fork.feature).

If needed, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: The first issue I said, sysOut is not capturing output values for karate.fork to validate. It returns only exitCode (0: represent script executed successfully, non-zero : represents the script error code). But I see the logs in DEBUG com.intuit.karate terminal and sysOut returns undefined

Comment: @ChandramohanRamabadran it works for me :) so it well may be a bug. an open source project relies on community feedback (and ideally code contribution) so I leave it to you as to how to proceed